# Puppet ensure file is directory OR link. Or ensure directory only if absent?

Tags: linux, puppet

2 CentOS servers that I'd like to apply the same manifest to. The manifest creates a user with a custom home directory location under `/var/username`

Problem is on one of the servers `/var/username` *has* to be a symlink off to `/data/username`. So simply running `ensure => 'directory',` would attempt to overwrite the symlink.

And I can't use `ensure => 'present'` because that creates a file by default if it doesn't exist. So for new servers that this manifest applies to a blank file will be created when I actually need it to be a directory.

1. Is there a way of doing `ensure` directory **or** link? So that if it's absent a directory is created. And if it's a link, then just leave it alone? By default the Puppet `file` type creates a file when doing `ensure => 'present'`.
2. Or a way of doing `if absent ensure directory else leave it alone`?

What about `exec`, doing a simple bash `if /var/username not exist then mkdir` sort of thing?
Nasty but it would work.

The ideal solution is probably to avoid special cases from the start. Having multiple config variants in a single manifest does seem a bit wrong. So eventually I will either:

- normalise the VMs (might switch from a symlink to a bind mount for example)
- give them separate manifests, since the configuration between them is different

But for the purposes of this question I would like to know if there are any options/syntax within Puppet that I currently don't know about.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use `$hostname` or `$certname` to handle the exception:

```
file { "/var/username":
mode    => 440,
ensure  => $hostname ? {
  'oddballserver' => link,
  default  => directory,
  }, 
target => $hostname ? {
  'oddballserver' => '/data/username',
}
```

That's untested, but based on logic I use for a variety of things in our manifests.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, you need to create a link in the /usr/share/applications/desktop Astra Linux directory from the root user. With the name of the link, the path where it leads and the shortcut. How can this be implemented by puppet manifest? I read the documentation and tried, but nothing came out(